# PLSQL dynamically filling an unbounded array

Tags: sql, dynamic, collections, plsql

I'm trying to declare and fill from the result of select an unbounded array, but I don't know if this is even possible. I've read some examples but there the unbounded array (nested or associative) is always filled with some concrete values. Could some one explain if it possible and where am I doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE myArray IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
    my_array myArray;
BEGIN
    SELECT RESOURCE_CALCULATE_ID
    INTO my_array
    FROM RESOURCE_CALCULATE rc
    WHERE rc.SERVICE_ID = 'some value'

    dbms_output.put_line(my_array.count);
END;
```

Solution using cursor after advice from [i100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505539/i100):

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR my_cursor IS
    SELECT <COLUMN>
    FROM <TABLE>
    WHERE <COLUMN> = <VALUE>;
  my_cursor_rec my_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor;

  LOOP
    FETCH my_cursor INTO my_cursor_rec;
    EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_cursor_rec.<COLUMN>);

    INSERT INTO TABLE
    SELECT
      <COLUMN1>,
      <COLUMN2>,
      <COLUMN3>
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE <COLUMN> IN (<LIST_OF_VALUES>)
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: See: [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select ... from returns an recordset or cursor. You cannot just select ... into

try something like this

```
DECLARE
    TYPE myArray IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
    my_array myArray;
    cursor c1 is
    SELECT RESOURCE_CALCULATE_ID
    FROM RESOURCE_CALCULATE rc
    WHERE rc.SERVICE_ID = 'some value';
BEGIN
    open c1;    
    fetch c1 bulk collect into my_array;
    close c1;
    dbms_output.put_line(my_array.count);
END;
```

Comment: I've fixed other way. You can see the solution above.

Comment: The statement _You cannot just select ... into_ is wrong. Bulk collect can be used with `select into` as can be seen e.g. from [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html).